# download multiple subsequent files from one server with one TCP handshake

Tags: android, tcp, download, android-asynctask

I try to create an application that can download files from a server in order to measure the speed that I can get with the particular server. I do this by using the Asynctask class. All the files that I want to download are located on the same directory. My question is, how can I download the subsequent files by keeping the connection and not by creating every time a new one? I know that for a TCP connection, there must be a 3-way-handshake established, before downloading a file. I want to connect to the server and then keep the connection and perform the download.

My code looks like this

```
@Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... sUrl) {

        try {
            speed=0; //initial value 
            int i=0;
            while ((i<sUrl.length)) {



            URL url = new URL(sUrl[i]); //sUrl[] contains the links that i want 
// for example http://myserver.net/file1.jpg, http://myserver.net/file2.jpg ... etc
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect(); //connection to be established 3WAY HANDSHAKE

            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;

                publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }
           long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long tempSpeed= (fileLength *8)/(finish-start);
            if (tempSpeed>speed) {
                speed=tempSpeed;
            }


            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close(); // connection is closed
            i++;
            }    
        }catch(Exception e) {
            exceptions.add(e);
        } 

        return 1;
}
```

By creating a new connection I loose time (for the download speed), because of the 3way handsharke . Also when transfering files in TCP, there is something called a tcp window (when you dowload data, initialy you start with low speed transmission, and if the connection is good this rate increases).
How can I do the above without creating and tearing down the connection for each file?

Comment: Is it possible to connect to a domain, for example, http://mydomain.com
and after connecting, request to download a file?
Can I do that with one TCP connection ? or will the request of a file (http://mydomai.com/myfile.txt ) cause a new connection and a new 3way-handshake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at you code, you keep receiving until the socket is close at the other side, so there is no way of using the same socket since it's closed.

If you can program both, the server and the client, then, I would suggest one possible way of doing it, and that is with a protocol, instead of receiving the file directly, the first packet you get is an integer which indicates the size of the file you're going to receive.  If that length is 0 (cero) it means there no more files and the connection should be closed.

At the server:

```
While (the_are_files_to_send) 
{
     Socket.write((int) FileSize);
     Socket.write(file's content);
}
Socket.Write(0); // No more files;
Socket.Close();
```

At the Client:

```
While ((size = Socket.read(buffer, 0, 4)) != -1) 
{
   int FileLength = convert_to _int(buffer);
   if (FileLength==0) break;
   Socket.read(FileLength bytes);
}
Socket.Close();
```

Comment: Write((int)FileSize) only writes one byte. You can't assume that a read of four bytes actually reads four bytes either. dataInputStream.readInt()/readLong() is the correct solution here.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not program the server. I can only program the client.

Comment: I also tried to instantiate the URLconnections before actualy retrieving the data. So that, when I executed the while loop, I had the connections already opened. However, this didn't work. The files could not be downloaded (exception)

Comment: I said write an integer, I don't know what language is using: C#, Java, C, Python, etc. So, I said write an integer whatever s/he needs to send an integer through a socket. About readInt() or readLong() it depend if the number is in the correct byte order. I prefer read 4 bytes and do the conversion myself.